# Spring-boot and spring boot dev tools integration not showing the updated class changes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-devtools

I am trying to follow [this example](https://dzone.com/articles/continuous-auto-restart-with-spring-boot-devtools) to do `spring boot` and `spring boot dev tools` integration to do automatic restart. The classes in the build folder are getting updated when i run `build --continuous` task but the application still talks to the old classes. In the example the `bootRun` task is as below. My project has its custom task for running the application. Right now with `build -continuous` when I make a change the application it is rebuilding the classes but the running application is not showing the changes. How to change my custom `h2Run` task so that it loads the changed classes? Thank you.

The boot run task in the example

```
bootRun {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + configurations.dev
}
```

My custom task for bootRun

```
class Run extends JavaExec {
    Run() {
        group "application"
        dependsOn project.tasks.classes, project.tasks.pathingJar
        classpath = project.files("$project.buildDir/classes/main", "$project.buildDir/resources/main", project.tasks.pathingJar.archivePath)
        main = "com.mycompany.Application"
    }
}

task h2Run(type: Run) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + configurations.dev // this is not working
    description "Start $appName using H2 database"
    args "--spring.profiles.active=dev"
    mustRunAfter 'cleanH2'
    dependsOn copyContentTypeLibraries
}
```

Comment: Please upvote the question if no one can answer. I need to get my reputations back. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I walked through the DZone article you linked to.  I didn't add your custom `Run` class or task, I just grabbed the `bootRun` task right out of the article. Even without any of your custom code, I initially experienced the same behavior you do.

The article states:

> 1. At the first terminal, start Gradle build as a continuous task:
>      `gradle build --continuous`
> 2. At the second terminal, start the Gradle bootRun task: `gradle
>      bootRun`

If I do these things, *in this order*, I also see my classes recompile, but the servlet container doesn't pick the changes up. Just like you describe.

However, if I do `gradle bootRun` **first**, and `gradle build --continuous` **second**, after the application is running, the application restarts as expected whenever I edit a java file.

Have you tried executing the commands in the two terminal windows in reverse order?

Comment: you are right I did not had to add any special Run task. It should just work when we add the dependency with the gradle bootRun task.